# How to get divs 100% of browser using css?

Tags: html, css

I have a number of divs within my html that I would like to be 100% width of the browser I have tired in my css to add `width:100%;` to each of the divs, none of the divs take the width of 100% and each divs seems to be a different width showing white spaces. I also tried to overflow: hidden; to each of the divs in the css but this hasn't worked.

Here is my html

```html
<body>        
    <div id="container">
        <div id ="pic">
            <img src="logo2.png"alt="me"/>
        </div>

        <div id ="about">
            <p>Here is example text</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id ="work">
        <p>Here is example text</p>

        <div id ="yearone">
            <h2>Year One</h2>        
            <p>Here is example text</p>
        </div>

        <div id="yeartwo">
            <p>Here is example text</p>
        </div>

       <div id="portfoilo">
           <p>Here is example text</p>
       </div>

       <div id ="otherwork">
           <p>Here is example text</p>
       </div>

       <div id="email">
          <p>Here is example text</p>

           <div class="social">
               <p>Here is example text</p>
           </div>
```

Here is my css

```css
#container
{
    width: 100%;         
}

#pic {       
    text-align: center;
    background:#D78B7D;        
}
   

h1 {
   font-family: "kepler-std-extended-display",serif;
}

#about {        
    text-align:center;
    background:#D78B7D;
   
    color: #fff;
    line-height:2.5;
    font-size:120.5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#work {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:2;
    width:100%;
    padding-left:45px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#62868D;
    padding-right:100px;
    padding-top:20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#yearone {
    padding-top:40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#yeartwo {
    padding-top:40px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#portfoilo {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    line-height:2;
    padding-top:30px;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    
    text-align:center;
    background:#D78B7D;
    
    padding-bottom:40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#otherwork {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    padding-top:30px;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    
    text-align:center;
    background:#62868D;
    
    padding-bottom:40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#email {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    line-height:2;
    padding-top:30px;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background:#D78B7D;
    padding-bottom:40px;
     overflow: hidden;
}

.social {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    line-height:2;
    padding-top:30px;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
  
    text-align:center;
    background:#62868D;
    
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is very simple. You are using `width:100%` and also using padding but padding increases the width so for that issue you need to set a css property `box-sizing:border-box` through which padding will be merged in width

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#container
{
    width: 100%;
     
}

#pic {
   
    text-align: center;
    background:#D78B7D;  
    
  
}
   

h1 {
  font-family: "kepler-std-extended-display",serif;
  }

#about {
    
    text-align:center;
    background:#D78B7D;
   
    color: #fff;
    line-height:2.5;
    font-size:120.5%;
     overflow: hidden;
}



#work {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:2;
    width:100%;
    padding-left:45px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#62868D;
    padding-right:100px;
    padding-top:20px;
     overflow: hidden;
}

#yearone {
    padding-top:40px;
     overflow: hidden;

}

#yeartwo {
    padding-top:40px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
     overflow: hidden;
}

#portfoilo {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    line-height:2;
    padding-top:30px;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    
    text-align:center;
    background:#D78B7D;
    
    padding-bottom:40px;
     overflow: hidden;
}

#otherwork {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    padding-top:30px;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    
    text-align:center;
    background:#62868D;
    
    padding-bottom:40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#email {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    line-height:2;
    padding-top:30px;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background:#D78B7D;
    padding-bottom:40px;
     overflow: hidden;
}





.social {

       padding:0;
    margin:0;
    line-height:2;
    padding-top:30px;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
  
    text-align:center;
    background:#62868D;
    
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
```

```html
<body>

    
<div id="container">

  <div id ="pic">

    <img src="logo2.png"alt="me"/>
    

</div>

<div id ="about">


<p>Here is example text</p>


</div>


</div>

<div id ="work">

<p>Here is example text</p>

    <div id ="yearone">

    <h2>Year One</h2>

    
 <p>Here is example text</p>
  


</div>

<div id="yeartwo">
<p>Here is example text</p>

 


</div>

<div id="portfoilo">

  <p>Here is example text</p>

   
        </div>

<div id ="otherwork">
<p>Here is example text</p>
        </div>


<div id="email">

    <p>Here is example text</p>

<div class="social">
<p>Here is example text</p>

    </div>
```

Comment: its working perfect in snippet...what is the problem left?

Comment: it doesn't change anything all by divs are still messed up

Comment: never mind I was able to get it fixed, thanks for your help

Comment: here is the fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/j52yh70L/ and its working perfect no divs going out of the frame

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to be 100% width of the browser I have tired in my css to add width:100%;

**Use Viewport units for CSS**

```
vw
1vw = 1% of viewport width
100vw = 100% of viewport width
```

Set your div width to `100vw` to get the width as much as the browser is.

[See compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

---

`width:100%` means make the element **width to 100% of its Parent**. if at all your parent has say some 20px width then your inner div inside this parent even if set 100% it just means 20px. So in your case all the padding margin etc will be taken into consideration and then the remaining width of the parent is the 100% width. using view port must resolve your issue easily. Else make sure your parent elements are 100% to the browser width by removing padding , margin etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` as alternative solution. 
with the `%` should all the parents take `height: 100%` to apply on it.

Check the reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Here is [demo](http://codepen.io/MRKS/pen/tgHun)